# How to add multiple image upload functionality in Django form.Imagefield()?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

How to allow users to upload multiple images through Django Forms, which was fetched in Django template by using form.ImageField()
it was providing the following output:

```
<input type="file" name="image" accept"Image/*" id="id_image">
```

This is allowing to upload only one image, But need to provide multiple upload option.

But I need the following output using Django Form with my custom class

```
<input type="file" multiple accept"Image/*" id="id_image" class="myclass1 myclass2">
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Django doesn't allow this, but I've done something similar by following along with this article [upload multiple images in django](https://studygyaan.com/django/upload-multiple-images-in-django). Another workaround is just to create a model for all of the image files and link in to your current model.